# Git Gui automatically opens repository

Tags: git, user-interface, repository

I need to use Git Gui for a project after a few months of not using it. 
I opened it and it immediately opens to a repository  C:/Users/Myusername
I cannot open another repository.

I have lost the options

[image]

How do I access the other repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you launch `git gui` from a repository directory it will open that repository. To see the screen you show above, run it from a directory that isn't managed by Git.

> it immediately opens to a repository C:/Users/Myusername

Are you deliberately tracking that directory with Git? If not, you may have accidentally created a repository there. Remove it and you should be back to normal.

Comment: Sorry, how do i do this?

Comment: @EmilyP, do you intend to track `C:\Users\Myusername`? (Normally I wouldn't recommend that.) If not, delete the `.git` directory it contains.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to use Git gui for a project after a few months of not using it

I recommend using the following tool which is much more rich in its capabilities and it will be much easier for you to connect to an existing repo.

You can simply open the new repository wizard and follow the required steps.

https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree

[image]

Comment: What _is_ that tool? You haven't named it or linked to it. It's pretty hard to identify it based on a screenshot. And is recommending a completely different tool really a good solution?

Comment: Sorry, missed the link, Thank you for mentioning it.

Comment: well i need to submit to bit bucket so is source tree easier to use?